# How to show a list in helm mode

Tags: helm

Suppose, we have a custom list we want to show to the user and allow him to select a value. I tried to use helm, but couldn't figure out how to do it:

```
(helm :sources '(("aaa" . 1), ("bbb" . 2), ("ccc" . 3))
  :buffer "*test*"
  :resume 'noresume
  :allow-nest t)
```

I though that it will pause the execution then when the user selects a value, it will return it. But I get an error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp 1)
  assoc-default(match ("aaa" . 1))
  helm-match-functions(("aaa" . 1))
  helm-initialize(noresume nil nil (("aaa" . 1) (\, ("bbb" . 2)) (\, ("ccc" 0.3))))
```

How can I make it output a simple list of values and get the selected value as an output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some nice examples in the [wiki](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki/Developing). I suggest you start there. Then read the documentation as you move forward. Here's a modified version of your function:

```lisp
(helm :sources (helm-build-sync-source "Test"
                 :candidates '(("aaa" . 1) ("bbb" . 2) ("ccc" . 3)))
      :resume 'noresume
      :buffer "*test*")
```